# removing the right most elements in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, methods, removeall

I want to remove the rightmost half of the list but this code sometimes is okay other time is not .

If l contains `A → B → C → D → E`, then after calling
`l.removeRightmostHalf()`, l becomes `A → B → C`.

```
public void removeRightmostHalf() {
  if (size % 2 != 0)
  {
    current = (size / 2) + 1;
    while(current <= size)
    {
      for (int i = current + 1; i < size; i++)
         nodes[i-1] = nodes[i];
      size--;
      if (size == 0)
        current = -1;
      else if (current == size)
        current = 0;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    current = (size / 2);
    while(current <= size)
    {
      for (int i = current + 1; i < size; i++)
        nodes[i-1] = nodes[i];
      size--;
      if (size == 0)
        current = -1;
      else if (current == size)
        current = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the work try it and tell me .
if my answer is right to you please don't forget to select it as correct answer.

```
public void removeRightmostHalf() {
    if (size % 2 != 0) 
        size=(size / 2)+1;

    else size=(size / 2);   
}
```

how is this do the work ? 
because the question is to delete the right half so decreasing the size to the half , that will make the right part of the array unreachable , just like what Arraylist.Remove() does .

Comment: Educate @swa by telling him why/what was broken, don't just give the answer. Also this code could be much much better, ie:

`current = (size / 2) + ((size % 2 != 0) ? 1 : 0)`

Then all the code duplication can be removed

Comment: @geoffrey because she's copying many things from remove() method and it doesn't make any sense in this place also she didn't ask why/what

Comment: @Zizoo, how so? 1) Your method could be reduced to a total of 3 lines with the same funcionallity, or even one if you dont care for formatting:

`current = (size / 2) + ((size % 2 != 0) ? 1 : 0);
while (current < size--) nodes[current] = nodes[current + 1];`

2) You did not explain what was wrong with his code.

Comment: @geoffrey go and submit your answer no one holds you

Comment: @Zizoo - Will do, was just giving you the opportunity since it is ultimately your answer.

Comment: @geoffrey 
if the array list contains  A,B,C,D,E , your method will make it A,B you did delete the last 3 elements this is not what she did explain  look at her example , if the elements is odd like 5 you delete the last 2

Comment: @Zizoo: Re read the line that sets `current`, it checks for oddness.

Comment: @geoffrey I tested it many times on Eclipse , it doesn't do what she asked for

Comment: @Zizoo: Then neither does yours as the logic is identical.

Comment: @geoffrey You did edit your answer many times, still doesn't work, in the last answer it displays all elements

Comment: Really... I noticed that there is some flaws in it, and yours also, have you even checked it? how does `nodes[current] = nodes[current + 1];` change on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @geoffrey yes you are right in this line doesn't change any thing just  the     size--;    make the right part unreachable , so I did improve the format in the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public void removeRightmostHalf() 
{
    if (size % 2 != 0)
       current = (size / 2) + 1;
    else
       current=size/2;
    nodes.subList(current,size).clear()
}
```